# Topless vs. Shirtless

Tags: meaning, word-choice, etymology, word-usage

If somebody asks me to describe the below photo, I would definitely say, "It is a picture of ***shirtless*** Putin on a horseback".

The adjective [***topless***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/topless) is defined by Oxford Online Dictionary:

> (Of a ***woman***) having the breasts uncovered: *a topless dancer*.

And according to Online Etymology Dictionary, [*topless*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=topless) means:

> ***of women***, "bare-breasted," 1966, from ***top (n.1)*** + -less.

And I looked up the bold ***top (n.1)*** above in the same dictionary and it states:

> Few Indo-European languages have a word so generic, which can be used
>   of the upper part or surface of just about anything.

And nothing else to clarify the meaning. However, the [headline](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/chelsea-handler-uses-topless-vladimir-putin-photo-to-highlight-instagram-nudity-inequalities-9831856.html) of [The Independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Independent) reads:

> Chelsea Handler uses ***topless*** Vladimir Putin photo to highlight
>   Instagram nudity inequalities

Questions:

1. Can the adjective ***topless*** describe a male? What is the difference between ***shirtless*** and ***topless***, then?
2. What does the noun ***top*** mean in ***topless***? What is its ***etymology***? (I can't figure out from Online Etymology Dictionary.)
3. Are there more apt/suitable words to describe the below picture besides ***shirtless*** (or possibly ***topless***)?

[image]

Comment: "Top" is often used to refer to a garment worn over the torso, such as a shirt or blouse. It is more commonly used when referring to women's garments.

Comment: Google Books claims 1230 instances of [**he** was topless](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+was+topless%22), which isn't *that* far behind the 1920 instances of [**she** was topless](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she+was+topless%22). But I'd probably say [he was **bare-chested**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+was+bare-chested%22) (according to Google Books, so would 3970 writers).

Comment: This is not one to get your shorts in a knot about, since there are no rigid rules (not even any squishy ones).  "Topless", absent any context, suggests to most healthy males a female who is naked from the waist up.  But it's sometimes applied to men, and of course it can be applied to a jar of peanut butter as well.  "Shirtless" is often used for men (and, yes, in the US), such as "The workmen were shirtless in the heat."  "Stripped to the waist" is also used (mainly for men, but occasionally for women).

Comment: I suspect the reason topless more often refers to women is because they're considered more likely to wear undergarments over their chest, specifically the brasserie, so they might not be effectively nude from the waist up even if they're "Shirtless". Additionally, even when men do wear underwear, it is usually a kind of shirt. Hence shirtless suffices for men, since it does imply that they are nude from the waist up. Technically, I suppose you could be shirtless and wearing a coat but coats usually aren't worn over bear skin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Topless  was originally used for males. Shirtless is much older. The idea was to indicate that the breast was not covered. I'd use topless only to refer to women, shirtless is used mainly referring to males [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shirtless%20man%2C%20shirtless%20woman%2C%20shirtless%20boy%2C%20shirtless%20girl%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshirtless%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshirtless%20boy%3B%2Cc0):

***[topless](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=topless&allowed_in_frame=)*** (adj.):

> - ***of women, "bare-breasted," 1966, from top (n.1) + -less. Earlier it was used of men's bathing suits (1937) and women's (1964).***  Earliest sense is "without a visible summit; immeasurably high" (1580s).

***[shirtless](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=&search=shirtless%20)*** (adj.)

> - c. 1600, from shirt + -less.

Comment: Earliest sense as in "Was this the face that launched a thousand ships, / And burned the topless towers of Ilium?"

Comment: I guess that is an example.

Comment: OED cites example of sartorial sense applied to males in 1969:   *"Observer* 7 Dec. 25/3   Topless boys with shoulder-length hair pause as they cycle past you: ‘Wanna buy some acid?’"

Comment: I have rarely, if ever, heard the term __shirtless__ in the US, but it would be understood. The phrase "without a shirt" would be used colloquially for men. Using the word __topless__ for a man might seen as facetious depending on the context. As above, __topless__ is readily used for women. Funny aside: the last time I was in New Orleans, there was a sign that read Topless Men, Bottomless Girls. I didn't go in.